# Providing direct links to Auth.Net admin, specifically refunding

Tags: authorize.net

I've got a frontend app that handles payments via Authorize.net. In the end, I've got a TransactionId attached to my own order object.

I would like to provide a direct link for my staff that takes them to the transaction in Authorize.net.

Our specific use case is for refunding, and I figured out this link in the sandbox: https://sandbox.authorize.net/UI/themes/sandbox/transaction/QuickRefund.aspx?TransID=1234567890

I would rather send them to the transaction, and let them click the refund button to get that page though.

This doesn't work: https://sandbox.authorize.net?TransID=1234567890

Anybody have any ideas? I could always write my own endpoint that does a refund via the api, but a direct link would be good enough and much easier if it exists.

Comment: Unless they've added something in the past ~18-20 months, I don't think it's possible to do, at least not elegantly.

Answer (score 0):

This functionality does not exist. You will need to build your own endpoint that uses their AIM API to process the refund.